# $().DataTables is not a function - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, datatables

I am using datatables inside Angular JS.

I have the following imports in header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controller.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Font Awesome JS -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js"
    integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js"
    integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But i get the error **$(...).DataTable is not a function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting `$.noConflict();` inside

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});
```

resolved the error